# Draw above UIWebView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, draw, qlpreviewcontroller

I'm looking for a way to draw "Lines" above a `UIWebView`.

I have a `UIWebView` that display a `PDF file`, the user should be able to add "Lines" and "Sketches" (simple one color lines etc) for sure this could be done with a `UIView` on top of the `UIWebView` but i m running into 2 logical problems.

First can the `UIView` where the drawing is, be transparent beside the lines - so you can view the `pdf` through it?

How could i handle the zooming in the `PDF`, if a user **zoom** the `WebView`, the `UIView` have to **zoom** "with each other" - so the drawing stays at the same `spot/zoom` level?

Is there any other way to display a `PDF` and add **drawings/annotations** to it? Currently i m using a `QLPreviewController` where i see no way to add any kind of annotations?

Is three any best practice for this?

Comment: Because `UIWebView` can do the zoom effect for you automatically.Try add a `gestureRecognizer` to the top view, and pass the same zoom gestureRecognizer down to your `UIWebView` after been handled in the top `UIView`?

Comment: thats what i tried but it never worked 1:1 for the top view.

Comment: @FabianBoulegue Did you find any solution for your question except the PSPDFKit ? Actually I am looking for solution for the same. Any links or suggestions would be great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PSPDFKit handles this (and many other hard PDF problems) very well. Using a web view for this kind of problem is likely to have many little corner cases. Any commercial product that has non-trivial needs around PDFs should definitely start there. For open source projects I don't have a great answer beyond "yeah, PDFs are a pretty tough; good luck."

That said, here are some starting points that may help you.

- You can turn off zooming with `webView.scalesPageToFit = false`
- You can get the current zoom scale using `webView.scrollView.zoomScale`
- I believe you can KVO observe `zoomScale` to track it while it changes, but you may only get the target value (which will cause you to lag).
- You can disable zooming (`scalesPageToFit`) and then re-implement it yourself with a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and `scrollView.setZoomScale(_:animated:)`. That way you could track the zoom changes better. You could also try to handle the animation yourself with a `CABasicAnimation` so that you could keep it in sync.

My experience with scroll views, web views, and PDF is that there are a lot of little funny interactions that will surprise you. Getting something that "kind of" works isn't that hard, but getting it really clean, smooth, and beautiful can be a nightmare. That's why I typically recommend PSPDFKit to clients. You'll generally spend much less on the license than on the custom development.

Comment: Thanks Rob, i thought there might be a work around for PSPDFKit as its a hobby project and i m not sure about there pricing.